# How to run particular suiteXmlFile from maven profile

Tags: maven, testng, maven-profiles

My maven profile looks like below and it has both **smoke** and **regression** XML but I want to run **only smoke or regression** how to do this?

```
<profile>
        <id>smoke</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/smoke.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, consider accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whatever you have in your pom under `<suiteXmlFiles>` you can override that by specifying it for running from cmd or your CI:

For running smoke only:

```
 mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/smoke.xml
```

For running regression only:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/regression.xml
```

For running both:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/smoke.xml,src/test/resources/regression.xml
```

Another option, as you already using profiles - to create three different profiles: smoke, regression, and general and provide the required one before run.